# 2003 Ford Expedition XLT 4.6 headlights/interior lights failure

Tags: ford, headlight, lights, led, expedition

I changed my headlights (low/high/parking) to LED, didnt like though thay all worked. Then changed to Xenon HID Halogen, didnt like though they all worked. Change back to regular Halogen & now the low beams, parking lights, & interior/dash lights wont come on. I replaced fuses & headlight switch for no change. The high beams & turn signal works & the fog lights only when high beams are on. ???

Answer (score 0):

Did you check electric wiring diagram ? You probably have further fuse location . If not, check the Lightning module . Could probably have overvolted on my opinion

Comment: Where can I find the module? I've check online but no results on videos or diagrams.